# OfficeJS, Angular 4 and native Outlook 2016 for Windows

Tags: angular, outlook, outlook-addin, office-js

I am getting an error when attempting to open an Outlook add-in in Outlook 2016 for Windows.

`Error: Office.js has not been fully loaded yet. Please try again later or make sure to add your initialzation code on the Office.initisalize function`

I have followed the recommendations listed in gist https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/docs/develop/add-ins-with-angular2.md to no avail.

I attempt to initialize Office in `main.ts` which works in browsers and on Outlook 2016 for Mac:

```
Office.initialize = reason => {
    launch();
};

function launch() {

  if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
  }

  const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
  platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to attach a debugger to your addin to look for errors? https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10

Comment: Yes I have but it isn't providing any useful information. The add-in remains uninitialized and about 5 secs after opening I get the error above with no further info. When reloading the add-in the F12 tool exits after which I need to reopen just to see the same error.

Comment: Hi David, please check my [code](https://github.com/Hongbo-Miao/office-addin-angular/blob/6a8756ed5a5f2eb6487baae9e4b6981b50c712db/src/main.ts#L13), let me know if it helps. I saw u mentioned it worked in macOS but not in Windows, would you mind creating a repo to reproduce? So I can see more details. Thanks